# Inject behavior for DOM elements in Blaze

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, handlebars.js

I want to be able to inject behavior for DOM elements via CSS. Example: if an element has class `clickToAlert`, clicking on it displays an alert.

With Spark, it was quite easy to achieve - I looked through the template DOM in `rendered` callback and enhance chosen elements.

```
Template.something.rendered = funciton() {
    _.each(this.findAll('clickToAlert'), function(element) {
        $(element).injectDesiredBehavior();
    });
};
```

However, with Blaze this will no longer be possible, as `rendered` callback will be called just once. So when later some data is inserted and new `.clickToAlert` element is added, it won't get the behavior.

What's the best solution?

---

To deflect the workarounds:

- Yes, there's a reason I don't just use `Template.something.events`. The actual behavior is much complex than that - think of reusable UI components with their events, styling, that also can respond to events from other part of the app (like [Bootstrap's affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)).
- I'd **really** like to avoid putting every such element in its own template as suggested [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#wiki-rendered-callback-only-fires-once). I've got just way too many of them, and this would shatter my app structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the old behaviour it is explained within an official example at https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback and there exists two different solutions, whichever suits you the most

**Old behaviour:**

The html:

```
<body>
  {{> list}}
</body>

<template name="list">
  {{#each items}}
    {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The javascript:

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection("items", {connection: null});

Template.list.items = function () {
  return Items.find();
};

var renderCount = 1;
var logRender = function () {
  console.log("rendered #" + renderCount);
  renderCount++;
};

Template.list.rendered = function () {
  logRender();
};

setInterval(function () {
  Items.insert({name: Random.choice(["one", "two", "three"])});
}, 1000);
```

**Solution 1:**

The html:

```
<body>
  {{> list}}
</body>

<template name="list">
  {{#each items}}
    {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The javascript:

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection("items", {connection: null});

Template.list.items = function () {
  return Items.find();
};

var renderCount = 1;
var logRender = function () {
  console.log("rendered #" + renderCount);
  renderCount++;
};

Template.list.rendered = function () {
  logRender();
};

Template.list.name = function () {
  logRender();
  return this.name;
};

setInterval(function () {
  Items.insert({name: Random.choice(["one", "two", "three"])});
}, 1000);
```

**Solution 2:**

The html:

```
<body>
  {{> list}}
</body>

<template name="list">
  {{#each items}}
    {{> justName}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="justName">
  {{name}}
</template>
```

The javascript:

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection("items", {connection: null});

Template.list.items = function () {
  return Items.find();
};

var renderCount = 1;
var logRender = function () {
  console.log("rendered #" + renderCount);
  renderCount++;
};

Template.list.rendered = function () {
  logRender();
};

Template.justName.rendered = function () {
  logRender();
};

setInterval(function () {
  Items.insert({name: Random.choice(["one", "two", "three"])});
}, 1000);
```